# Extending a root partition in Linux

Tags: linux, partition

I have a primary partition `/dev/sda3` which is mounted on `/` (`root`) filesystem of size 45 GB.

We have a requirement to extend it to 100 GB. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you have enough free space around sda3.

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you have spare free space. You can use partition editor tools like [gparted](https://gparted.org/) for displaying and editing the current disk layout. Just be careful to backup all important data before you do it. DWYOR.